# ThreadLocalRandom double 2 decimal

Tags: java, decimalformat

I try to print my Array Double with only 2 decimals. But I can not find in google how to do. Please any help?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class java_05_16_05_01 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Double> salary=new ArrayList<Double>();
        int NumberPersonSurveyed = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10+1);
        for(int i=0; i<NumberPersonSurveyed; i++){
            double salaryPerson = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1000, 10000+1);
            salary.add(salaryPerson);
        }
        System.out.println(salary);
    }
}
```

Actually the OUTPUT is:
[9803.056390825992,
2753.180103177606, 
2602.5359323328644, 
3319.2942269101018]

But I Expect:
[9803.056,
2753.18, 
2602.53, 
3319.29]

Note I want use ThreadLocalRandom instance of Math.random or similar. 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are simulating salaries, you could simply generate `int` values, which will be in cents, and then divide by 100 (and convert to double) to get your result.
Like so:

```
double salaryPerson = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100 * 1000, 100 * (10000 + 1)) / 100d;
```

This approach frees you from string formatting issues, and also allows you to process your data with the exact values if you wish to perform extra operations besides printing.

Comment: how to do? like this:
System.out.println("Mix Salary: " + salary.get(0)*100/100);
is not working

Comment: You may still need a formatter due to floating point errors. e.g. `0.1d` is actually stored as `0.100000001490116119384765625d`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this, the most common way I have seen is based off of the C style `printf`.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", sal);
```

`printf` uses modifiers determined by `%` operators. This one specifies that it should print floating point number (the `f`) with 2 decimal places (the `.2`). You can find a list of operators [here](https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm).

Personally I prefer the C# styled [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0,number,0.00}", sal));
```

`MessageFormat` backends off of [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which represents a number in contexts of `#` and `0`, where a `#` represents a potential but not required number, while a `0` represents a required number. Which is to say if you pass `10` into the specified format it would print `10.00`.

**Edit**:

Just realized it was an ArrayList; you're going to have to iterate through each member of the array and print them out individually.

```
boolean USE_PRINTF = false;
System.out.print("[");
for(int i = 0; i < salary.size(); ++i)
{
    if(USE_PRINTF) { System.out.printf("%.2f", salary.get(i)); }
    else { System.out.print(MessageFormat.format("{0,number,0.00}", salary.get(i))); }
    if(i < salary.size() - 1) { System.out.print(", "); }
}
System.out.println("]");
```

Comment: Hi! I try to do your first suggestion: System.out.printf("%0.2f", salary); 
But I get a ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %0.2f
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkNumeric(Formatter.java:3079)
 at ....
******
And your second answer, I get this ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Comment: @JhonScott I fixed the code to work with arrays, and to print it similar to how `ArrayList` prints it.

Comment: Hi van, is not working, look the error:
[Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %0.2f
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkNumeric(Formatter.java:3079)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkFloat(Formatter.java:3058)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2784)

Comment: @JhonScott Sorry about that, I don't typically use `printf`, the `0` before the `.` was incorrect.